# How to display the closest number from my database when a user does a search?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using PHP and MySQLi for a search calculator with different prices and different quality for range of products.

I would like to know if it is possible that when a user searches for $5000 and there is no $5000 in my database, the closest that I have is $5002 and the different descriptions of the product. How do I display the $5002 product and its description rather than an error message when the user keys in $5000?

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Rapaport WHERE RapNinety='$rap90' ORDER BY `RapNinety`  ") or die("Please Fill In All Blank Fields");
$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
if($count ==0){
    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('')</script>";
```

Comment: Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. Never insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: To address the question...is there an acceptable range within which you want to search? e.g. if there's something priced within +/-$500 then display it? Or you just want literally the nearest one by price, even if the user said $5000 and the nearest is $10?

Comment: use query statements: LIKE, BETWEEN, (column > $var OR column < $var)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should define near. I called it diff in this code

```
$diff = 10;
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Rapaport WHERE ABS(RapNinety - $rap90) < $diff ORDER BY `RapNinety`") or die("Please Fill In All Blank Fields");
```

Then use $query how ever you want.

**EDIT:**
Also you can use this query:

```
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Rapaport WHERE RapNinety  > $rap90 - $diff AND RapNinety  < $rap90 + $diff ORDER BY `RapNinety`") or die("Please Fill In All Blank Fields");
```